# changing img onclick using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I am new to jQuery and have searched for my answer but without any exact answer.
Lets say I have an image of a box. I want the box to change to another image when clicked on. If the image is clicked again it will go back to a box.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    function changeImage() {
        if (document.getElementById("animals").src == "lion.jpg") {
            document.getElementById("animals").src = "box.jpg";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("animals").src = "lion.jpg";
        }   }

</script>
```

my html

```
<img src="box.jpg" id="animals" onclick="getValue()" />
<img src="lion.jpg" id="animals" onclick="getValue()" />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: But there's no jQuery there. Oh, and IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of element clicked as an argument in your `onclick` function by using `this`

You probably want something like:

HTML:

```
<img src="box.jpg"  onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(element){
   element.src = element.src === 'box.jpg' ? 'lion.jpg' : 'box.jpg';
}
```

I have no idea what you were trying to do with function named `getValue()` shown in your markup

Comment: Except `element.src` will always be an absolute URL (and will never be equal to `'lion.jpg'`); you should (almost certainly) use `element.getAttribute('src')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jQuery, here's how you can do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-image]').on('click',function() {
    var newImage = $(this).data('image');
    $(this).data( 'image', this.src );
    this.src = newImage;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5shA8HsX0Eojw5BGHKrh4v0l2VosV7Dr37SW4jwgdhbATy1yEm6ismw" class="animals" data-image="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3_huaTLnaerihPDAQGId2Rte-uQuS1ylTFPJCUKPPHxcB7zLhooRHGg" />
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQkyEb17ZBn31tVrGP53bOGvT66Rg6SKueB2XFv-NHRfvmXS2D-JfmR2bM" class="animals" data-image="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScoskjmn10XRwl4zc_Brm_YwH0fsNRkicqe46gWTCMHzPLmr0s97lSs4o" />
```

Comment: Quite true ... kind of ignored them because I did not even use them . Will remove so they are not a distraction.